# how to get conditional column selection in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm  trying to make a query that will give the appropriate column by user selection.

If user select cab:
i.e. where `user_choice='cab'`
Then it will give `l.price_cab column`

If user select seat:
i.e. where `user_choice='price'`
Then it will give `l.price_seat column`

Query:

```
SELECT l.company_name, l.price_seat, l.price_cab
from login l JOIN users u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement to return different columns based on criteria. Here's how you can do it:

```
SELECT
l.company_name,
CASE
    WHEN user_choice = 'cab' THEN l.price_cab
    WHEN user_choice = 'price' THEN l.price_seat
END as price
from login l JOIN users u
```